# How to show msg.value in ether

Tags: solidity, contract-design

So this works:

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

  contract test{
    event Print(string _name, uint _value);
    function test() payable{
        uint testval = 5;
        Print('val',(testval * 1000000000000000000));
        Print('val2',(5 ether));
    }
  }
```

And I get the same value for val1 and val2.  Is there anyway to do:

```
Print('val3',(testval ether);
```

I keep getting an error on the function and multiplying out my contract value by that amount is rather annoying

Answer (score 2):

*In my opinion* it's best to deal in wei in the contracts. Go ahead and emit wei so clients get the true values in input/output.

Presentation is usually best treated as a client-side issue. You can use something like fromWei() to do the conversion.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3fromwei

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the event you defined `event Print(string _name, uint _value)`

You should log the event like so...

```
function emitEvent(string _name, uint _value) public {
     Print(_name, _value);
}
```